# Cannot pass view model back to controller using jquery dialog and model binding with Razor MVC 4

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggling to get my dialog to pass back the full model passed to the view with values binded.

Here is my script:

```
var scId = 0;
var monthId = 0;
var initializeDialogs = function () {
$('#read-transactions-dialog-form').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 650,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function () {
            $('#form-read-transactions').submit();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    open:
        function(event, ui) {
            $(this).load("/Month/ViewTransactionsForSubCategory/?scid=" + scId +     "&mid=" + monthId);
    }
});

function loadId(scid, mid) {
scId = scid;
monthId = mid;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$('a#read-transactions').click(function () {
    $('#read-transactions-dialog-form').dialog('open');
});

initializeDialogs();
});
```

My View Dialog:

```
@model OnlineBudget.WebUI.Models.TransactionsViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitTransactions", "Month", new { tvm = Model.Transactions },   FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-read-transactions" })) 
{ 
<div id="read-transactions-dialog-form" class="modalDialog" title="Transactions">
<table class="table">

@if (Model.Transactions.Count() > 0)
{
    <tr><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th><th>Description</th><th>Exclude</th><th>Delete</th>    </tr>
}

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Transactions.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Transactions[i].Id); @Html.HiddenFor(model =>     Model.Transactions[i].Title); @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Transactions[i].Date);   @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Transactions[i].Amount); 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Transactions[i].SubCategoryId);    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Transactions[i].MonthId);

    if (!Model.Transactions[i].IsDeleted)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.Transactions[i].Date.ToShortDateString()</td> <td>@Model.Transactions[i].Amount</td><td>@Model.Transactions[i].Title</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Transactions[i].Excluded)</td><td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Transactions[i].IsDeleted)</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</table>
</div>
}
```

And lastly my controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewTransactionsForSubCategory(int scid, int mid)
    {
        TransactionsViewModel tvm = new TransactionsViewModel { MonthId = mid, Transactions = transactionRepository.Transactions.Where(t => t.SubCategoryId == scid &&  t.MonthId == mid).ToList() };

        return PartialView("ReadTransactions", tvm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult  SubmitTransactions(List<OnlineBudget.Domain.Entities.Transaction> tvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //foreach (var tv in tvm.Transactions)
            //    transactionRepository.SaveTransaction(transactionRepository.Transactions.Where(t => t.Id ==  tv.Id).First());
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I recently changed the post controller to accept only a list og transactions instead of TransactionsViewModel but that didnt work either. I keep getting either nulls or an empty list in this case, but there is definitely data populated in the table in the dialog.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with MVC accepting collections as parameters similar to this before. I ended up switching my javascript call to doing an $.ajax post ($.post also has some issues sometimes) speficically including a content and data type

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'Post',
   dataType: 'json',
   url: 'url-goes-here',
   data: JSON.stringify({ data: data}),
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Not quite as nice as the auto-binding, but it does post the data back even as a collection.

Comment: How would I get my model into the data variable?

Answer (score 0):

I use $.postify like this for posting complex js objects to MVC:

e.g.

```
var postData = {
    id : 123,
    childArray : [
        { subid : 456, value1 : "Foo" },
        { subid : 789, value1 : "Bat" }
    ]
};

$.post("postRoute", $.postify(postData), function(response) {
    // stuff
});
```

See: http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/post-complex-javascript-objects-to-asp-net-mvc-controllers/